# @< Symbol In Prolog

Tags: prolog, operators

I want to know what `@<` means in Prolog?
I encountered this symbol in this line of code while reading about the Bridge and Torch Problem:

```
select_one_or_two(L, [Sel1,Sel2], L2) :- 
   select(Sel1, L, NewL),
   select(Sel2, NewL, L2),
   Sel1 @< Sel2.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comparative operators that start with `@` are more general than the ones that don't. With operators such as `</2`, you can only compare numeric values and expressions (involving literal numerics and variables that are instantiated with numeric values). So, with `</2` you can do this:

```
?-  X = 2, Y = 3, X + Y < 2*Y.
X = 2,
Y = 3.

?- X = 2, Y = 3, X + Y > 2*Y.
false.

?-
```

But you will get an error in the following cases if the expressions don't evaluate to a known numeric:

```
?- Y = 3, X + Y < 2*Y.
ERROR: </2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Or:

```
?- a < b.
ERROR: </2: Arithmetic: `a/0' is not a function
```

However, using `@</2` you can compare lots of different types of objects in prolog. The comparison evaluation follows the rules described in the link that @Ankur gave. To understand these rules, you'll need to know what Prolog terminology means, such as `term`, `functor`, `atom`, etc (see, for example, [Prolog Terms](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_terms.htm))

Looking at some examples:

```
?- a @< b.
true.

?- a(1) @< a(2).
true.

?- b(1) @< a(2).
false.

?- 20 @< a.
true.
```

These are pretty straight-forward, following the rules. Here's a more interesting case (from above):

```
?- Y = 3, X + Y @< 2*Y.
false.
```

Why would `X + Y` be considered "not less than" `2*Y`? Prolog would internally look at this as:

```
`+(X,3) @< *(2,3).`
```

(Note `Y` is instantiated to `3`.) These are compound terms (they aren't individual atoms or variables). If we look through the comparison rules, the matching rule is:

> Compound terms are first checked on their *arity*, then on their *functor*
>   name (alphabetically) and finally recursively on their arguments,
>   leftmost argument first.

The *arity* of both *terms* is 2. The *functor* names are `+` and `*` respectively. Those are different. And in teh ASCII collating sequence, `+` comes after `*`. Therefore it is not true that `+` "is less than" `*`, and therefore not true that `+(X,3) @< *(2,3).` Thus, it is not true that `Y = 3, X + Y @< 2 * Y.`

Note also that `@</2` doesn't evaluate numeric expressions. So even with `X` and `Y` instantiated as values, you will get:

```
?- X = 2, Y = 3, X + Y @< 2*Y.
false.
```

Whereas, when we had `</2` here, this is true, since the expression `X + Y < 2*Y`, when evaluated, is true. When variables are simply unified, it understands that, however, so you would have:

```
| ?- X @< Y.

yes
```

But on the other hand:

```
| ?- X = 2, Y = 1, X @< Y.

no
```

In this case `X @< Y` is seen as `2 @< 1` due to the unification of `X` with `2` and `Y` with `1` and the numeric rule kicks in.

Having said all that, the use of `@</2` in the predicate `select_one_or_two` enables that predicate to be usable on lists of all sorts of objects, not just numbers or fully instantiated numeric expressions. If it had used `</2`, then the following would work:

```
?- select_one_or_two([2,1,3], X, Y).
X = [2, 3],
Y = [1] ;
X = [1, 2],
Y = [3] ;
X = [1, 3],
Y = [2] ;
false.
```

But the following fails:

```
?- select_one_or_two([b,a,c], X, Y).
ERROR: </2: Arithmetic: `b/0' is not a function
?-
```

However, with the `@<` operator, it works:

```
?- select_one_or_two([b,a,c], X, Y).
X = [b, c],
Y = [a] ;
X = [a, b],
Y = [c] ;
X = [a, c],
Y = [b] ;
false.
```